# Mongo 2.7.3 Do a join between 2 collection (mongo Shell)

Tags: mysql, database, mongodb, shell

I am working on a project using mongo 2.7.8 so no "look-up" command.

I am using Mongo shell in studio 3T (called intelliShell)

What I try to do might looks like a join in SQL.

Problem:

I have 2 collections (A and B). The documents from collection A  that I query with `db.collectionA.find({conditions: "true"})`, I want to also collect data from `db.collectionB.find({conditions: "$get:4")`;

for the same user I need to have all the field from collection A + one field of collection B .

Thank you

Comment: If lookup  is not an option, you  need to do it on application level. In case of 'intelliShell' it is javascript. Did you try anything?

Comment: My issue is that I am using IntelliShell cause I want to export result as CSV so Need to be done in One query ..

Comment: And what stops you to store results in a temporary collection and export it in "One query"?

Comment: Hum I would say the huge amount of data, but thats an idea I should try

Comment: Well, having your constraints, you don't have much options.

Comment: Right.. Can you give me an example about how to do that please ?

Comment: Please show your attempts **in the question itself**. I believe you are familiar with https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What tool are you referring to with "mongo 2.7.3"? If that's a `mongo` shell or `mongod` [server version](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/#mongodb-version-numbers) you would be using a very early development/unstable release of what eventually would become the MongoDB 3.0 production release series and should definitely upgrade to a production release. Can you confirm the MongoDB server version reported by `db.version()`?

Comment: the mongoDB server version reported by db.version() is 2.7.8. The website I am working on has been developped 2 or 3 years ago